# Redundant assignment vs check before assignment in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, design-patterns, performancecounter

In front of a long loop, it costs more (processor + memory) to assign redundantly the same value, or to check before the assignment?

```
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<100_000; i++){
    if (...) {
        count++
        doLogic(count); // logic is strictly related with count
    } else {
      count = 0;  //50.000 redundant assignment
    }
}
```

**VS.**

```
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10_000; i++){
    if (...) {
        count++
        doLogic(count); // logic is strictly related with count
    } else {
        if(count > 0) { // 50.000 checks 
          count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And would it cost the same if `count` would be present in a different object (injected as a singleton in a Spring context) and the increments/check/reset would be like:

```
config.incrementCount();
config.getCount();
config.resetCount();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is *it doesn't matter*. Either approach will have roughly same performance and most probably will be dominated by `doLogic`.

Your first choice should always be to write simple and idiomatic code instead of doing premature optimization.

---

The long answer is *it depends* (it always does, doesn't it?).

First of all, you don't really know what kind of optimizations [JIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html) will do to your code. What is true for one platform and Java version may not be true for another. You can't rely on anything that is not explicitly *guaranteed*.

Second, you know what they say about premature optimization. It's always a good idea to benchmark and profile your code, but even benchmarks are not 100% reliable.

Ok, let's benchmark:

```
# First case, variable counter
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
Benchmark1.testCounter    avgt    8  0.149 ± 0.026  ms/op
Benchmark1.testCounterIf  avgt    8  0.190 ± 0.036  ms/op

# Second case, counter in the wrapper class
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
Benchmark1.testCounterClass    avgt    8  0.198 ± 0.025  ms/op
Benchmark1.testCounterClassIf  avgt    8  0.181 ± 0.016  ms/op
```

[Benchmark code](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/a23e16d35d7a1e6cacf003ac8f6f3f16)

While for the case with simple counter variable the "if optimization" seems to lose, in the second case the difference is within the margin of error.

In my benchmark I just used a simple static field holding `Counter` class. Looking at the ASM, generated by JIT, it appears that method calls were inlined. Your situation may be different, as enterprise java and Spring are infamous for doing obscure magic behind the scenes (e.g. via proxies and bytecode manipulation). Not only methods may not be inlined, but also some hidden overheads may emerge unexpectedly.

---

P.S. If you are interested in performance and microoptimization for JVM, I suggest to read [Alexey Shipilev's JVM Anatomy Quarks Series](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/).

Comment: thank you for the exhaustive answer! really appreciate the reference to "JVM Anatomy Quarks"